# Does this calculation have a name?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, metric, softmax

In my recurrent neural network I can calculate a confidence score of an output sequence during evaluation (ground-truth not known) using the following:

1. Compute the softmax of each word in the output sequence
2. Take the natural logarithm of the max probability for each word
3. Sum the resulting values together

I think this is related to maximum log likelihood, but we aren't performing cross-entropy, so I'm a bit confused at the relationship.

Does this calculation that I've outlined have a name?